# Word VBA web scraping-how can I scrape certain classes & skip others

Tags: vba, web-scraping, ms-word

I'm trying to sequentially scrape certain classes from a web page, but not others. However, I cannot work out how to selectively choose the "sub" classes I'm interested in - `transcript-question` and `transcript-answer`, but *not* `timestamp`, which all seem to be inside `transcription-item-wrapper`.

Is there an elegant way to do this, or do I need to work with the extracted string and remove unwanted HTML code?

Current code:

```
Sub ScrapeToWord()
Const URL = "http://......."
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
Dim topics As Object, posts As Object, topic As Object
http.Open "GET", URL, False
http.send
html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("transcription-item-wrapper")
For Each posts In topics
    For Each topic In posts.getElementsByClassName("transcript-question")
        ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = topic.innerText
    Next topic
Next posts
End Sub
```

A snippet of the HTML code:

```
    <div class="transcription-section">
        <div class="transcription-section-wrapper">
        <div class="transcription-item-wrapper"><div class="transcript-qa"><div class="timestamp"></div><div class="transcript-question">Tape 01</div></div></div><div class="transcription-item-wrapper"><div class="transcript-qa"><div class="timestamp">
            <p class="34" id="01003400">01:00:34:00
            </p>
            <span class="listen"></span>
            <span class="watch"></span>
          </div><div class="transcript-question">Could begin with a brief overview of your life.</div></div><div class="transcript-qa"><div class="timestamp"></div><div class="transcript-answer">I was born in 1942. I was born on a farm and started school when I was 4 years old.</div></div></div><div class="transcription-item-wrapper"><div class="transcript-qa"><div class="timestamp">
            <p class="60" id="01010000">01:01:00:00
            </p>
            <span class="listen"></span>
            <span class="watch"></span>
          </div><div class="transcript-question">And then?</div></div><div class="transcript-qa"><div class="timestamp"></div><div class="transcript-answer">During the Depression my father lost the farm then we moved to Sandridge and I went to school there until I was about 8. We then went dairy farming there and</div></div></div><div class="transcription-item-wrapper"><div class="transcript-qa"><div class="timestamp">
          <p class="90" id="01013000">01:01:30:00
          </p>
          <span class="listen"></span>
          <span class="watch"></span>
        </div><div class="transcript-answer">no machine milking in those days, it was all hand milking. </div></div><div class="transcript-qa"><div class="timestamp">
```

Comment: I don't see an actual valid URL listed here.  Maybe you can import everything and filter out what's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelectorAll to gather a nodeList of items and use the two classes of interest with CSS OR syntax to match on either. Then loop the list to do whatever you want with the matched items.

```
Dim i As Long, nodeList As Object

Set nodeList = html.querySelectorAll(".transcript-question, .transcript-answer")

For i = 0 To nodeList.Length-1
    Debug.Print nodeList.item(i).innerText 'do something with each return value e.g. put in a table or print out
Next
```